# How can I get \timing result in client code?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to write each query's time to disk.

How can I get the time of `\timing` and `explain analyze` total runtime in client code?

Comment: Which client, precisely, do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure PostgreSQL to log this information in the server log, which is likely to be easier than doing it client side.

Setting `debug_print_plan` will cause PostgreSQL to log the query plan.

Setting `log_duration` will cause it to log query duration.

It is also possible to have these log messages sent to the client by setting `client_min_messages` appropriately, although the usefulness of this will depend on how the client handles them.

`log_min_duration_statement` is also likely to be useful to prevent your life from blowing out by logging only long running statements.

The [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) describes this and other useful settings.

Comment: But in this case : LOG:  duration: 4.455 ms  statement: SELECT .... the 4.455 is recorded at server client. so this time does not include time taken to transfer data to client, right? it's also does not the time to execute a query, because the time is much larger than EXPLAIN ANALYZE.